# Script keeps overwriting Array

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

So basically I have to following script. When I click it, data gets pushed into an array. But whenever I click it, the array size just stays the same and elements aren't being added, it will just stay one element long. What am I missing?

```
$(document).on('click', '#favoriteadd', function() {
    var favorites = [];
    favorites.push($('h5').text());
    console.log(favorites);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing the `favorites` variable to empty each time you click.

Try this:

```
var favorites = [];
$(document).on('click', '#favoriteadd', function() {
  favorites.push($('h5').text());
  console.log(favorites);
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You're creating a new array every time you run the function.  Use a global variable or pass an array into the function.